# C++ When restarting my hangman game my score gets deleted along with player info which I dont want

Tags: c++

I'm making a hangman program and it works fine except when the game ends it restarts and makes the user input their user again and the score gets restart. How do I fix this I really need help.I want it so that when you restart the game your name and score from the previous game is the same. I cant figure out the algorithm to do so. I know I probably messed in my main function where I used the copy constructor but I can't figure another way to restart the words. Can someone help me!

In my player.h file I have:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    void MakeGuess(char &guess);
    void Win();
    void Lose();
    char Agree();
private:
    string name;
    int score;
    string myString;
    char answer;
};

#endif
```

In my hangman .h file I have

```
#ifndef HANGMAN_H_
#define HANGMAN_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

class Hangman
{
public:
    Hangman();
    char Play();
protected:
    Player player2;
    vector<string> words;
    string THE_WORD;
    string soFar;
    string used="";
    int wrong;
    char guess;
    int count;
    int maxwrong=0;
    int x;
    void RespondIncorrectGuess();
};


#endif
```

In my hangman implementation file I have:

```
#include "hangman.h"
#include "player.h"

Hangman::Hangman()
{
    wrong=4;
    guess='a';

    cout<<"welcome to a dangerous game of hangman! Good luck "<<endl;

    words.push_back("MONKEY");
    words.push_back("HANGMAN");
    words.push_back("DIFFICULT");

    srand(time(NULL));
    x=rand()%3;

    THE_WORD=words[x];

    cout<<words[x]<<endl;
    soFar = string(words[x].size(),'-');
    cout<<soFar<<endl;
}

char Hangman::Play()
{
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"The number of incorrect guesses you have left is: "<<wrong<<endl;

        player2.MakeGuess(guess);
        RespondIncorrectGuess();

        if(wrong==maxwrong)
            player2.Lose();

        else if(soFar==words[x])
            player2.Win();

        if(wrong==maxwrong||soFar==words[x])
        {
            cout<<"The word was: "<<words[x]<<endl;
            if(player2.Agree()=='Y')
            {
                cout<<"player has agreed to play again. Now restarting game.."<<endl;
                return 'Y';
            }
        }
    }
}

void Hangman::RespondIncorrectGuess()
{
    if (words[x].find(guess) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";

        // update soFar to include newly guessed letter
        for (int i = 0; i < words[x].length(); ++i)
            if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
            {
                soFar[i] = guess;
            }
        cout<<soFar<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
        cout<<soFar<<endl;
        --wrong;
    }
}
```

In my player implementation file I have

```
#include "player.h"

Player::Player()
{
    cout<<"Enter your name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<name<<" ";
    score=0;
    myString="random";
}

void Player::MakeGuess(char &guess)
{

    cout<<"Enter your guess"<<endl;
    cin >> myString;
    guess=myString[0];

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    if(myString.size() > 1)
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if((isdigit(guess)))
        {
            cout<<"error"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    guess = toupper(guess);//convert the string into the first letter
}

void Player::Win()
{
    cout<<"Congratz you win " <<name<<endl;
    ++score;
    cout<<"Your score is: "<<score<<endl;
}

void Player::Lose()
{
    cout<<"I'm sorry but you have been hunged"<<name<<endl;
}

char Player::Agree()
{
    cout<<"Would you like to play again"<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter Y or y for yes, N or n for no"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;

    if(answer=='y'||answer=='Y')
    {
        return 'Y';
    }

    else if(answer=='n'||answer=='N')
        exit(1);

    else
    {
        cout<<"Invalid command. The program will now exit"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And finally in my main file I have:

```
#include "player.h"
#include "hangman.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Hangman game1;

    while(1)
    {
        if(game1.Play()=='Y')
        {
            game1=Hangman();//the name/score gets restarted which i dont want but i want everything else to get restarted like the word 
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant  lines where you store / restore

Comment: @Marged I thought showing the whole code was very important because if I just showed one line then you might want to see the other part.Ill comment the line where things go astray though!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the line `game1 = Hangman();` you are creating a new object Hangman and assigning it to `game`. Meaning everything `game1` had will be gone and it will start as a new game1. One alternative is to create a constructor for `Hangman` that will create a new object `Hangman` with same the same player or create a copy constructor. Example(copy constructor):

```
Hangman::Hangman( const Hangman& _hangman ){
    this->player2 = _hangman.player2;
}
```

And

```
if(game1.Play()=='Y')
    {
        game1=Hangman(game1);
        continue;
    }
```

Also, in C++11 you can also delegate constructors, meaning calling a constructor from another constructor. Let's say, in case your default constructor initializes other aspects of `Hangman` and you don't want to write it again, you can:

```
Hangman::Hangman( const Hangman& _hangman ) : Hangman(){
    this->player2 = _hangman.player2
}
```

Comment: if I try to use game1=Hangman(game1.player2); it says player2 is a protected member

Comment: @user5001170 forgot it was private, in that case a copy constructor would do. Fixing it.

Comment: can you show me the syntax for fixing this with a copy constructor I'm a little bit confused because I tried using a copy constructor before

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be incorrect, but I think it's because your Hangman constructor makes a new Player every time it is created based on the .h file, referred to as Player 2.  Right now you don't have it set up to store that Player's information between games.  An easy fix would be to pass a Player to the Hangman constructor as a parameter, and then call all of the player methods with the passed-in Player.